# How to get correct width for view with content by systemLayoutSizeFittingSize when height gived

Tags: ios, width

I want to calculate view size with autolayout, but it can not get right value. Here is my code

```
// build views
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
let posterView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 100))
let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 20))

 titleLabel.text = "Title  "
 titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16) // label height = 19.5

 view.addSubview(posterView)
 view.addSubview(titleLabel)

 posterView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) in
     make.top.left.right.equalTo(view).offset(0)
     make.width.equalTo(posterView.snp_height).multipliedBy(16.0 / 9.0) 
 }

 titleLabel.snp_makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.top.equalTo(posterView.snp_bottom).offset(0)
    make.left.equalTo(view).offset(0).priority(750)
    make.right.equalTo(view).offset(0).priority(750)

    make.bottom.equalTo(view.snp_bottom).offset(0)
 }

 // calculate 
 view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

 let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, height: 90+19.5)
 view.addConstraint(heightConstraint)

 let fittingSize = view.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize) 
 // the fittingSize is (40,109.5), not expect value (160, 109.5)
```

Please don't tell me how to calculate dynamic height for UITableViewCell. This is a opposite problem from height to width.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing this in code?

Comment: I am sure. thank you

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me as problematic. I would guess your problem lives in your `priority` settings. As a suggestion, I'd configure your view in Interface Builder. I think you'll find problems like this are much easier to diagnose than in code. If you need to update a constraint programmatically, you can drag an `IBOutlet` of the CONSTRAINT from the storyboard and manipulate it programmatically from your view controller.

Comment: I would add a height constraint to `posterView` instead of `view`.

Comment: I've recreated these constraints in Interface Builder and got the same result. What happens is, the label gets stretched vertically and playing with priorities did not help. However, I've managed to do what you, probably, want by adding UIView, putting label inside of it and setting a constraint equating the heigh of that view with the height of the label. Please let me know if you need a more detailed explanation.

Comment: @dan thank you, but the problem is you doesn't know the height for the poster. The poster's height equals  view's height minus label's height.

Comment: @Baglan Thanks, I'll try you solution

Comment: @Baglan I add some code as you say, but it does not work.

Comment: @Baglan I add some code as you say, but it does not work.

    <pre><code>
    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    let wrapView = UIView()
    wrapView.addSubview(titleLabel)

    titleLabel.snp_makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.edges.equalTo(wrapView)
        make.height.equalTo(titleLabel.snp_height)
    }

    view.addSubview(wrapView)

    wrapView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.equalTo(posterView.snp_bottom)
        make.left.right.equalTo(view)
        make.bottom.equalTo(view.snp_bottom)
    }
    </code></pre>

Comment: Is the poster's height not 90?  Anyway you should fix it by raising the vertical content hugging priority of the label.

Comment: @Wangchao here's a link to download the .xib of my experiment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/103292/40287730.xib it works in Interface Builder so, I assume, if the same constraints are expressed programmatically, it should work in code too. Good luck!

Comment: @Baglan I know it work perfect in interface builder, but it doesn't work in code.

Comment: Hi @Wangchao, I've managed to do it with code too; here's the gist: https://gist.github.com/Baglan/d954ada18447a61bd98aabe92802330f but you will need to translate it to whatever library you are using for AutoLayout

Comment: I guess the essence is that you need to set a high vertical "content hugging priority" otherwise the label gets stretched vertically. Perhaps it can even be done without the container view for the label. Good luck!

Comment: @Baglan thanks, I will try it.